# What is the size of lot for options listed in Yahoo finance?

Tags: stocks, options, call-options

I am wondering what is shares lot size of options for any stocks in finance yahoo list. For example in [this particular AMZN call option](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN210319C03170000?p=AMZN210319C03170000) ask price is 251.85, expires in March 2021, and the strike is ATM. Does that mean that buying 1 option for 251.85 gives me a right to buy 100 shares of AMZN until March with current stock pricing?

I am wondering that 100 shares of AMZN will cost 318 100$ and 251.85 is just 0.08% of that total cost of 100 shares. So this number is just looks unrealistic for me, since for only 0.08% fee you basically "freezing" price for 4 months. Could someone explain me, what is the shares lot size indicated there, may be it is price for 1 share option?

Comment: @DStanley Sorry, all of these answers were carrying similar information, but the last one I like that it's much simpler to understand for newbee like me (according to my question and points)

Comment: Okay fair enough - I was just making sure I wasn't missing something. Glad it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The prices in the options market are shown *per share*.  For example $251.85 is per share of underlying.
- Each option contract is typically for 100 shares.  This is called the *multiplier*. Anything other than 100 is called a Special Delivery Option which typically come up when certain corporate actions occur (e.g. splits, spin-offs, acquisitions, special dividends etc.).
- Purchasing 1 option contract at $251.85 when the contract has the typical multiplier of 100 would cost $25,185.00.

**What is the typical multiplier for a US Exchange-listed option?**

**100 shares.**

See [Understanding Stock Options](http://www.cboe.com/learncenter/pdf/understanding.pdf) for more background.

Answer (score 1):

The "lot size" for equity options is 100 shares. (Technically it's one *contract*, but the terms of the contract will specify that it's for 100 shares)

> Does that mean that buying 1 option for 251.85 gives me a right to buy 100 shares of AMZN until March with current stock pricing?

No - it mean that you have the right to buy 100 shares of AMZN for $3,170 *per share*. That one option costs $251.85 *per share*. So one contract will cost you $25,185.

It *also* means that the price of AMZN would have to rise to a *break-even* price of $3,421.85 per share (plus commissions) for the option to be profitable overall. If AMZN is below the strike ($3,170) at expiry you're just out your premium. If it's between the strike and the break even price, you'll get *some* of your premium back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does that mean, that I should multiply the price of option by 100, so if I see premium price 251.85$, that means it's real cost is 25 185?

Comment: That's how much you'd pay to buy 1 option contract on 100 shares, yes.

Answer (score 1):

One option costs $251.85, giving you the right to buy 100 shares until March expiration for $3,170 per share for a total cost of $3,421.85 per share.

Today's closing price was $3,185.07 so you would be agreeing to buy the stock for 7.4% more than today's close.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So premium price 251.85$ means per share or per 100 shares?

Comment: A call option give the holder the right to buy 100 shares of a company at a specific price, known as the strike price, up until a specified date, known as the expiration date.